# Webpack: How to load raw HTML as React JSX?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

I'm using Webpack and React JSX. I have a section on my app that has a lot of static content that come from Designers. They usually send me a HTML file with the content that I need to publish.

Currently, I'm manually converting these HTML's to JSX (through setting HTML dangerously).

**Question**: Is there a loader in Webpack that will automatically convert HTML files to React JSX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to [html-jsx-loader](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/html-jsx-loader) to automatically convert raw HTML to React JSX using Webpack.

1 - Add the **html-jsx-loader** to your Webpack configuration:

```
{
    ...
    module: { 
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.htm$/, loader: 'jsx-loader!imports?React=react!html-jsx-loader'}
        ]},
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.htm']
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you can write raw HTML (e.g. Introduction.htm) and webpack will automatically convert the content of this file to a React component.

Finally, you can reference this component in your JavaScript code as follows:

```
var Introduction = require('./Introduction'); 

//Introduction is not HTML but ReactJS class.
```